# How to change the font size and color of the back "<" in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to change the size and color of the back "<" button in Xamarin.iOS? I have the following code but the only part it change is the navigation back text:

```
var attribute = new UITextAttributes();
attribute.TextColor = UIColor.Red;
attribute.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(15.0f, UIFontWeight.Regular);
UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(attribute, UIControlState.Normal);
UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(attribute, UIControlState.Highlighted);
```

[image]

Update, here's the new `NavigationPage` renderer:

```
public class NavigationPageRenderer : NavigationRenderer
{
   public override void ViewDidLoad()
   {
      base.ViewDidLoad();

      UIButton backBtn = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);
      var size = new CGSize(25,25);

      UIImage backImg = UIImage.FromBundle("back").ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
      var newBackImage = ScalingImageToSize(backImg, size);

      backBtn.SetImage(newBackImage, UIControlState.Normal);
      backBtn.SetTitle("Back", UIControlState.Normal);
      backBtn.SetImage(newBackImage, UIControlState.Highlighted);
      backBtn.SetTitle("Back", UIControlState.Highlighted);   

      backBtn.TouchUpInside += (sender, eve) => {
         this.NavigationController.PopViewController(false);
      };

      NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem(backBtn);
      NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.Red;
   }

   public UIImage ScalingImageToSize(UIImage sourceImage, CGSize newSize)
   {
      // Your code here

   }
}
```

**More Update:**

Using the code above, I added the image below which looks different than the normal iOS back button to see if it is really getting the message:

[image]

and found out that the code above does not change the "<" image to the new arrow image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `UINavigationBar` Tintcolor for this:

```
 UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.Red;
```

Comment: Thanks. I know about this. This would change the color but not the font size

Answer (score 1):

**Cause:**

the icon "<" in backButton is an image ,not text.So,even if you set the style of the title,it still didn't work.

**Solution:**

If you want to set the style of the icon "<" ,you can create a new **BackButton** in your viewcontrollers.

First download an icon "<",and put it in assets.Refer to the following code.

```
UIButton backBtn = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);
backBtn.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 30, 30);

UIImage backImg = UIImage.FromBundle("back").ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);


backBtn.SetImage(backImg, UIControlState.Normal);
backBtn.SetTitle("Back", UIControlState.Normal);
backBtn.SetImage(backImg, UIControlState.Highlighted);
backBtn.SetTitle("Back", UIControlState.Highlighted);

backBtn.TouchUpInside+= (sender, eve) => {

  this.NavigationController.PopViewController(false);

};

this.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem=new UIBarButtonItem(backBtn);
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.Red;
```

And here is the [icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Uux0.png), you can download it.

**Update**

If you want to set the image size ,use the following method

```
/*
sourceImage:the iamge that you download
newSize the size you want ( for example 25*25)
*/
public UIImage ScalingImageToSize(UIImage sourceImage,CGSize newSize)
{

 if(UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale==2.0) //@2x iPhone 6 7 8 
  {
    UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 2.0f);
  }


 else if(UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale == 3.0) //@3x iPhone 6p 7p 8p...
  {
    UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 3.0f);
  }

 else
  {
    UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(newSize);
  }

 sourceImage.Draw(new CGRect(0, 0, newSize.Width, newSize.Height));

 UIImage newImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

 UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

 return newImage;

}
```

Comment: Hi Lucas. Quick question, so to change the size of the back button I have to add a smaller image correct? Thanks

Comment: No,if you want to change the size,backBtn.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 20, 20);

Comment: Actually im sorry but I just tested this more thoroughly today but it is not working. The arrow size is still the same

Comment: Thanks for all the patience. Just to make sure, I added all these code in my `NavigationPage` renderer. Is that the right place? If so, it still doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: I added my renderer code to my post. Please check. Thank you

Comment: You can call it in viewwillappear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188971/discussion-between-iamsophia-and-lucas-zhang-msft).